# How can I reference an array when I don't know the name of it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my Cloud Firestore I have a database comprised of several users, and on their structure there's an array called `contacts` that has several nested arrays. The id (or name, if you will) from every single of one of those arrays is the id from another user. Like so

```
"contacts": [
   "UserAid": [
      "value1",
      "value2",
      "value3"
   ],
   "UserBid": [
      "value4",
      "value5"
   ]
]
```

The thing is, I want to delete `value2` from `contacts`. However, the `UserAid` is actually a value generated at random by an UUID generator. I know that deleting a value from an array is as simple as:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('Users')
        .doc(user.id)
        .update({
           array: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(`${valueName}`)
        })
```

However, because in this case "array" on the update function is a dynamic value (aka the uuid of another user), how can I reference "UserAid" on my function to delete de value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[]` notation to use the value of a variable as the property name. So:

```
const fieldName = "theFieldNameThatYouWantToUpdate"
firebase.firestore().collection('Users')
        .doc(user.id)
        .update({
           [fieldName]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(`${valueName}`)
        })
```

If you don't have the name of the field to update, you'll have to first load the document to determine that.